# extract string from text file using batch file

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, text, extract

I have iis log file that contains like this:

```
Line 4780: 2014-12-01 00:58:25 10.211.200.33 - 10.211.55.6 80 POST /localhost/logon.aspx username=michael&CAMUsername=GROUP1&CAMPassword=@SzbRERF&CAMNamespace=zCORP
Line 4781: 2014-12-01 00:58:25 10.211.200.33 - 10.211.55.6 80 POST /localhost/logon.aspx username=john&CAMUsername=GROUP3&CAMPassword=@SzbRERF&CAMNamespace=zCORP
Line 4782: 2014-12-01 00:58:27 10.211.200.33 - 10.211.55.6 80 POST /localhost/logon.aspx username=daisy&CAMUsername=GROUP1&CAMPassword=@SzbRERF&CAMNamespace=zCORP
```

and I want to extract that file. I will get text output like this:

```
michael GROUP1
john GROUP3
daisy GROUP1
```

Anyone can help me to do this?

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "iis_log=c:\iis.log"

for /f "useback tokens=2,4 delims==&" %%a in ("%iis_log%") do (
    echo %%a %%b
)


endlocal
```

Comment: thank a lot, but not works for me

i try using powershell script, but it failed<br/>$input_path = 'D:\iis.log'
$output_file = 'D:\output.log'
$regex = ‘\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+[username]+=[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[CAMUsername]+=[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+&\b’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file

Comment: @WahnanAhmalAsysyakiry - what you mean by `not works`.is there any kind of error?Output is not the one you want?

Comment: i've made batch file using your script, but i got nothing for the output. then i try create powershell script '$input_path = 'D:\iis.log' $output_file = 'D:\output.log' $regex = ‘\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+[username]+=[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[CAMUsername]+=[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+&\‌​b’ select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file'

Comment: @WahnanAhmalAsysyakiry - not even an error message? I've tested the script with the content you provided and works.Only thing you need to do is to change the log location.

Comment: what should i do, if want to make the output written to txt file? let say output.txt

Comment: @WahnanAhmalAsysyakiry - if your bat is called e.g. `iisLogParser.bat` call it like this `iisLogParser.bat > output.file`

Comment: sorry, i have tried it but the output not like what i want. To make it simple, i want to take the substring "username=michael&CAMUsername=GROUP1&" and ignore the other string at every line. can you help me?